# Significance of 0xff

Tags: c, pic18

I was wondering was 0xff, 0x00, and 0x0f represent. TRISA, TRISB, and TRISC are the ports being used on my board.

```
void main()
{
TRISA = 0xff;
TRISB = 0x00;
TRISC = 0x00;
ADCON1 = 0x0f;
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I programmed the code given in a textbook but from curiosity I wanted to know what 0xff , 0x00 , and 0x0f does to the rest of the code. I skimmed through the book but I couldnt find any reference on that. @artm

Comment: What board and what book are you using?

Comment: @CEPB using a pic18f4620 microcontroller and RGB LEDs

Comment: They're just hex constants. `0xff` is the largest unsigned 8-bit number, having all bits 1, so that might be its significance.  Likewise `0xf` is the largest unsigned 4-bit number, and of course `0x00` is zero and has all bits zero.

Comment: @NateEldredge awesome that makes sense, Thanks alot :)

Comment: To understand why those bit patterns are used, [read the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39626e.pdf) and have a look at your boards schematic.

Answer (score 1):

`TRISA` is the tristate controller bits for I/O line A. This turns on or off the tristate gates that select whether the output register powers the pins or not. With the tristates off, the pins are input pins.

I'm not absolutely sure since I haven't checked the manual in over 10 years but I think 0xFF turns on all the tristates, so all the pins are input pins. I could have it backwards though.